# why get error: "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, build

I look a sample

Dockerfile

```
ARG some_variable_name
# or with a default:
# ARG some_variable_name=default_value

RUN echo "Oh dang look at that $some_variable_name
# or with ${some_variable_name}
```

docker build

```
$ docker build --build-arg some_variable_name=a_value
```

result

```
Oh dang look at that a_value
```

but, I used the sample always gets error

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Why? Was I lose something?

Answer (score 3):

in addition to @Ridwan answer, MAKE SURE THERE IS NO ADDITIONAL WHITE SPACE IN BETWEEN
`docker build -t mytag .`

Comment: This save me 3 days of suffering

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to put a dot, which represents that the Dockerfile in the local directory.

By that I meant:

```
docker build -t mytag .
```

What you were previously doing was:

```
docker build -t mytag
```

Thus forgetting to put the dot.

Comment: Do please vote as answer if it works for you

Comment: Thanks, but I add a dot 
[docker build --build-arg some_variable_name=a_value . ]
I get other error : 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.421MB
Error response from daemon: no build stage in current context

Comment: Yes, a second error here is that your Dockerfile is invalid. However, @Ridwan 's answer explains why you where getting the error you asked about. I would advise to check a getting started with Docker tutorial. See https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: I refer to the practice of this URL(https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/), is there anything missing from this Dockerfile example? Does Dockerfile have to have a FROM command? I just want to show the incoming the value of --build-arg.