# unable to prepare context: path " " not found for Github Actions Runner

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, github-actions

I am trying to build and tag a docker image in Github Actions runner and am getting this error from the runner

```sh
unable to prepare context: path " " not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have gone through all other similar issues on StackOverflow and implemented them but still, no way forward.

The interesting thing is, I have other microservices using similar workflow and Dockerfile working perfectly fine.

**My workflow**

```yaml
name: some-tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env: 
      AWS_REGION: us-east-1
      IMAGE_NAME: service
      IMAGE_TAG: 1.1.0

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Create cluster
        uses: helm/kind-action@v1.2.0

      - name: Read secrets from AWS Secrets Manager into environment variables
        uses: abhilash1in/aws-secrets-manager-action@v1.1.0
        id: read-secrets
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          secrets: |
            users-service/secrets
          parse-json: true

      - name: Build and Tag Image 
        id: build-image
        run: |
          # Build a docker container and Tag
          docker build --file Dockerfile \
          --build-arg APP_API=$USERS_SERVICE_SECRETS_APP_API \
          -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
          echo "::set-output name=image::$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"

      - name: Push Image to Kind cluster 
        id: kind-cluster-image-push
        env: 
          KIND_IMAGE: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}
          CLUSTER_NAME: chart-testing
          CLUSTER_CONTROLLER: chart-testing-control-plane
        run: |
          kind load docker-image $KIND_IMAGE --name $CLUSTER_NAME
          docker exec $CLUSTER_CONTROLLER crictl images
```

**Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:14 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS development

COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --production
RUN cp -R node_modules /tmp/node_modules
RUN npm install 
RUN rm -f .npmrc 
COPY . .

FROM development AS builder
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
RUN yarn run build
RUN rm -f .npmrc 
RUN ls -la

FROM node:14-alpine AS production

# Install curl
RUN apk update && apk add curl

COPY --from=builder /tmp/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./


ARG APP_API
                        
# set environmental variables

ENV APP_API=$APP_API

EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

I guess the problem is coming from the building command or something, these are the different things I have tried

**I used --file explicitly with period(.)***

```yaml
docker build --file Dockerfile \
          --build-arg APP_API=$USERS_SERVICE_SECRETS_APP_API \
          -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
          echo "::set-output name=image::$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

**I used only period (.)**

```yaml
docker build \
          --build-arg APP_API=$USERS_SERVICE_SECRETS_APP_API \
          -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
          echo "::set-output name=image::$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

**I used relative path for Dockerfile (./Dockerfile)**

```yaml
docker build --file ./Dockerfile \
          --build-arg APP_API=$USERS_SERVICE_SECRETS_APP_API \
          -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
          echo "::set-output name=image::$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

**I used relative path for the period (./)**

```yaml
docker build \
          --build-arg APP_API=$USERS_SERVICE_SECRETS_APP_API \
          -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG ./
          echo "::set-output name=image::$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

I have literally exhausted everything I've read from SO

Comment: You failed to include which of the many steps you provided is producing that message, but my suspicion is that `$USERS_SERVICE_SECRETS_APP_API` is being expanded and introducing something you don't want. There are two ways to troubleshoot that: (a) quote the arg and see if it fixes it `--build-arg "APP_API=$USERS_SERVICE_SECRETS_APP_API"` (b) `set -x` on your step and see what the shell sees; I'd strongly recommend quoting `"$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"` also, since it's only risk, no reward, to leave them bare like that

Comment: @mdaniel I've tried putting the quotations around the --build-arg values but still to no avail

Answer (score 2):

The problem was basically a white-spacing issue. Nothing could show this. Thanks to [This Github answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69033092/16069603)